# Why does CMake report gcc version unknown?

Tags: android, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a program into android using CMake.  When I try to compile using arm-gcc it checks the compiler with no problem but when it checks for the version it gives a gcc version unknown error.

A snippet of the code is here

```
if("${gcc_version_RESULT}" STREQUAL "0")
  if(NOT GCC_VERSION)
    execute_process(
      COMMAND "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/config_tests/gcc_version"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
  endif()
```

I am not sure where the problem is.  I have tried deleting the CMakeCache, export CC. Please help me.

Comment: The problem was with with the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ i has to add -fexceptions because arm compiler has exception handling disabled by defaults. " gcc_version.cpp" had exception handling thing inside its code